# How to get refetchQueries data in reactjs 16.8

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, hasura

I'm trying to use **refetchQueries** to get an updated list of record after a mutation. I have tried below code to get updated data but the updated data showing in **network tab** of the developer console.

This is for reactjs 16.8 and "react-apollo": "^2.5.5" and it seems **awaitRefetchQueries: true** not working

```
client.mutate({
        mutation: ADD_ACTIVE_CREW,
        variables: {
          activeCrewInfo: {
            employee: activeCrew[0].vp_id,
            date_on_crew: new Date(),
            crew_id: selectedCrewId
          }
        },
        options: () => ({
          refetchQueries: [
            {
              query: GET_EMPLOYEE_BY_CREW_ID_QUERY,
              variables: { crew_id: crew_id }
            }
          ]
        }),
        awaitRefetchQueries: true

      });
```

I'm getting correct response in developer console's network tab, but not able to access in my reactjs application.

Comment: `.then(() => this.setState(whatever))`

Comment: ` .then(result => {
        const arrUpdatedData = result.data;
        console.log(arrUpdatedData);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
`
I have checked with the above code but it not getting correct data.

Answer (score 0):

The mutation data itself will never reflect the refetched queries.

Any queries you tell Apollo to refetch will be requested and then have their result written to the cache. That means any `Query` components or components using `useQuery` or `watchQuery` will be updated, provided the `query` and `variables` parameters match what's in `refetchQueries`.

If you don't already have a component that uses that query, you need to add one.